# Построение двух пиков

Tags: python

Написал код для расчета дифрактограммы. Представил его краткую версию. Функция `caushi()` преобразует пик в распределение с шириной `gamma()`

```
def gamma(labd, d, thet):
    return labd * 1.15 / (d * math.cos(thet / 2))

def caushi(x, x_0, gamma):
    return 1 / math.pi * gamma / 2 / ((x - x_0)**2 + (gamma / 2)**2)

arr = np.zeros(1800)
x = np.linspace(0, 180, 1800)

num = 10

rr = np.zeros(1800)
x = np.linspace(0, 180, 1800)

num = 10

for i in range(num):
    from random import randint
    number = randint(0, np.size(D))
    sinthet1 = 1 * lambdal / (2 * D[number - 1])
    sinthet2 = 1 * lambdbt / (2 * D[number - 1])
    if sinthet1 <= 1:
        thet1 = math.degrees(np.arcsin(sinthet1)) * 10
        th1 = np.around(thet1).astype(int)
        arr[2 * th1] = I[number - 1]
```

Часть дифрактограммы имеет следующий вид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь вопрос: как сделать правильно наложение пиков, чтобы не было такого "врезания" с падением?

Answer (score 5):

По картинке видно, что вы заполняете массив, присваивая ячейкам сначала значения для одного пика, потом для другого.

А нужно ведь складывать значения, а не заменять.

Вместо

```
array[i] = value[k-й пик в точке i]
```

делать

```
array[i] += value[k-й пик в точке i]
```

Comment: значения Y не сохраняются

Comment: Что это значит?

Comment: Максимальные значения при таком объявлении суммируются с существующими. А у меня это конкретные значения, которые должны сохраняться

Comment: Видимо, нужно придумать оконную функцию, значение которой быстро, но плавно достигает нуля в координатах соседнего пика. Искажение амплитуды пиков из-за фона или наложения хвостов соседей в спектроскопиях/хроматографии реально существует, от этого никуда не деться.